# Upload file to a website via Python script

Tags: python, authentication, file-upload, automation

I want to upload a file from my computer to a file hoster like hotfile.com via a Python script. Because Hotfile is only offering a web-based upload service (no ftp).

I need Python first to login with my username and password and after that to upload the file. When the file transfer is over, I need the Download and Delete-link (which is generated right after the Upload has finished).

Is this even possible? If so, can anybody tell me how the script looks like or even give my hints how to build it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For a similar task, I've previously used [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/), with some quite success.
Note: although I was not uploading files, its documentation [says](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/ClientForm/) that it is capable to handle also file uploads.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you want to use Python to upload a file using HTTP "put".  You will need to use a Python library that lets you do HTML stuff; a good choice might be [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) which is included with Python.

A Google search for "Python HTTP put" found me this:

http://inamidst.com/proj/put/put.py

This appears to be complete working code that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You mention they do not offer FTP, but I went to their site and found the following:

> How to upload with FTP?
>   ftp.hotfile.com user: your hotfile
>   username pass: your hotfile password
>   You can upload and make folders, but
>   cant rename,move files

Try it. If it works, using FTP from within Python will be a very simple task.

Comment: There is one thing I hate about FTP: it transmits your login credentials *unencrypted* over the Internet.  If the HTTP solution uses SSL encryption, that is very much preferable.